# Stock NVIDIA MacBook Pro in Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, catalina, software-update, gpu

There are some MacBook Pros for example from 2013 which have an NVIDIA graphics card built in by Apple and they are supported under macOS Mojave or Catalina. But if you upgrade one of those models to Catilina, will you lose your NVIDIA graphics and be stuck with the Intel Iris one or does this only apply to eGPUs, user-upgraded GPUs and with Hackintoshs? To my mind, just losing your NVIDIA graphics is rather unlikely as Apple does not have any warnings regarding this on their website, but I am asking here so I can be completely certain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [2013 MacBookPro with Nvidia GPU and recent macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375354/2013-macbookpro-with-nvidia-gpu-and-recent-macos)

Comment: Yes, I did not find that article when I googled the issue. My apologies and thank you!